# How to embed medium post on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, velo

so I am trying to embed the latest entrepreneur profiles from Medium@femalefounderssg into a site made on Wix, I tried to use the JSON and jQuery code here: https://codepen.io/jasonm4130/pen/vZYbQx

```
var tagIndex = item.description.indexOf('<img'); // Find where the img tag starts
var srcIndex = item.description.substring(tagIndex).indexOf('src=') + tagIndex; // Find where the src attribute starts
var srcStart = srcIndex + 5; // Find where the actual image URL starts; 5 for the length of 'src="'
var srcEnd = item.description.substring(srcStart).indexOf('"') + srcStart; // Find where the URL ends
var src = item.description.substring(srcStart, srcEnd); // Extract just the URL
output += '<div class="blog-element"><img class="img-responsive" src="' + src + '" width="360px" height="240px"></div></header>';
```

The issue I am facing is that since the code renders the first  content that it sees, it always renders the logo (as in the image below), the entrepreneur profile photos that I want displayed with the posts are usually contained in the second

[output of above code in my implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8BXy.jpg)

Could anyone please advise as to how the existing code can be modified or what other possible implementations are there? Thanks so much!

Comment: Consider using JQuery instead, it will make this much easier